# jquery-file-upload file arrives as random numbers

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

So I have the jquery file upload script running on my webserver, with a target-url pointing to a local mac server with apache/php, and when I go to upload a file the script shows the progress bar and it completes, and it arrives to the correct directory and everything on the mac, but the file is an assortment of numbers like:

1390865006

or

1390865033

and it should be noted that those files are about the correct size, but even if I add .jpg to the end of the file name they won't open as images.

Am I missing some crucial something somewhere? I hope it's not my mac being too old, I didn't see any requirements for php version in jquery file upload, but I am running 5.2.8

Thanks

*** EDIT ***
This was resolved by upgrading PHP to 5.5.8

Comment: well, its some thing  inside the php server code...file is given a name and saved from server side....post dat if you want us to help

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by upgrading PHP to 5.5.8